# Git merge master into development branch is overwriting, not merging

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a problem where my master changes are completely overwriting my changes in a development branch, instead of merging them.

I have a master and a development branch for a web application. I am currently working on features that will take a few weeks to implement, but at the same time other developers are continuously adding to master.

Let me use one file as an example, `functions.php`

I am making many lines of changes in the `functions.php` file within the `dev` branch.

Occasionally I switch to master using `git checkout master` and pull from the online using `git pull origin master`. This brings the team changes inline with my local dev.

Now, I want to introduce those changes into my `functions.php` file in `dev` branch while maintaining my work I have done thus far. So I checkout the `dev` branch and I run `git merge master`. The thing is, the functions file in `master` branch is COMPLETELY overwriting my functions file in `dev` branch.

Why?

To summarize my workflow:

```
git checkout master # Move to master branch
git pull origin master # Get down local changes, all along I have been working in dev and making dev progress
git checkout dev # move to dev branch
git merge master # attempt to align team changes to my dev branch
```

my files are overwritten, NOT merged.

Thank you,
Simon

Comment: Are you committing every-time before checkout to  master

Comment: Committing master or dev? Both were committed. It does not seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Check your "**config**" file inside your "**.git**" folder of your local repository or global.
In that, if **notes.mergeStrategy** is configured to "**theirs**", then your changes will be overwritten. You just need to remove that configuration and everything will be fine.

Ref:

1. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config
2. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes

Comment: Hmmm, there is no such configuration for `notes.mergeStrategy` in my config. Here's my config output:

`[core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = true
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 ignorecase = true
 precomposeunicode = true
[remote "bitbucket"]
 url = https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx.git
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/bitbucket/*
[branch "master"]
 remote = bitbucket
 merge = refs/heads/master `

Shall I add it and use `notes.mergeStrategy` and set to `mine`?

Comment: This is such as common scenario, surely this does not warrant a complex solution. I would imagine more than 50% of people need to commit to dev branch from master to keep as many changes aligned as possible.

Comment: @SimonDowdles Did you find the solution to your issue?